# Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2018 PaymentJournal contract change caused custom API to fail

Tags: navision

For some reason Microsoft changed the contract definition for PaymentJournal removing the underscored in one property only!

The error message was: "Parameter  of the type Applies_to_Doc_No in method PaymentJournal_Port in service PaymentJournal_Service is invalid!"

Does anyone know why would they do it? It broke our API. Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Old property in NAV 2013 R2:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Applies_to_Doc_No" type="xsd:string"/>
```

became in NAV 2018:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AppliesToDocNo" type="xsd:string"/>
```

In case anyone else has the same issue. There you go.

No idea why they would remove the underscores. WHY?!?!?

Comment: That makes no sense. Especially knowing that all of the other params stayed the same with underscores.